# RTMP Shared Object

Tags: actionscript-3, object, flash, rtmp, shared

There are a simple way of using RTMP shared object in 2018? A framework, simple app etc. I'm reversing a old flash game, but can't find a RTMP server with shared object support.

RED5 is over complicated.

Comment: Over a decade ago there were about 3 servers that supported RTMP: Flash Media Server (official, easy to use, expensive), Wowza (cheaper third-party solution, never had any experience with it) and Red5 (free, open-source and, indeed, overcomplicated to use). If you google for **free RTMP server** (why didn't you do that first?) there seem to be a **nginx**-based solution and also some others.

Comment: @Organis Because they don't have shared object feature.

Comment: I have no idea how to use Red5, Wowza is paid.

Comment: If you have already researched other solutions and they won't do, you should have mentioned that in your question. Now, it seems there are no **simple** ways. So, it's either **Red5** to crack for you, or you can substitute remote **SharedObject** with a custom server solution (HTTP or sockets, depends on what that app of yours needs).